# how can i send the data from one post request api to another post request api in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I created two post api in nodejs one is login and another one is dashboard api. I want to send the email, role data from login api to dashboard api.Can anyone give me the solution for this problem?Advance Thankyou for your answer.

```html
var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'JILLU',
    cookie:{maxAge:60*60*24*1000},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
   var  ses = req.session;
    ses.id=req.session.id;
    ses.email=req.body.mailid;
    ses.role=req.body.role;
    console.log(ses.id);
    res.redirect(307,'/dashboard');
});
app.post('/dashboard',function(req,res){
    console.log("dashboard");
    if(ses.email) {
        console.log("email is a live");
        console.log(ses.email);
        console.log(ses.role);
        console.log(ses.id);
        res.write(ses.email);
        res.write(ses.role);
    } else {
        console.log("login first");
        res.render(__dirname+"/mailrequest.html");
    }
});
app.listen(8086,function(){
    console.log("App Started on PORT 8086");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
// '/login'
   app.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
    var  ses = req.session;
     ses.email=req.body.mailid;
     ses.role=req.body.role;
     console.log(ses.id);
     res.redirect(307,'/dashboard');
    });

    // '/dashboard'
    app.post('/dashboard',function(req,res){
     console.log("dashboard");
     if(req.session.email) {
        console.log("email is a live");
        console.log(req.session.email);
        console.log(req.session.role);
        console.log(req.session.id);
        res.write(req.session.email);
        res.write(req.session.role);
    } else {
        console.log("login first");
     res.render(__dirname+"/mailrequest.html");
    }
});
```

The problem was that the variable ses was local and was undefined in '/dashboard' route whereas session is an object of the req(request) object.

And I suggest you to use http get request for dashboard instead of post.